# Bluetooth headset stuttering on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth

My headset works fine when it's first turned on, but if I stop listening to music for a few minutes, I guess the headset goes to sleep. When I start listening again, the audio stutters, and is on a time delay. If I turn the headset off and back on, when it reconnects to Ubuntu, it starts playing music from before I disconnected, even if VLC is currently paused (and it still sometimes stutters).

My laptop: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834314016
Bluetooth 4.0+HS

My headset: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B014132JF0?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014132JF0)
Bluetooth 4.1

Other issues:
Sometimes turning my laptop's bluetooth and/or my headeset off and back on doesn't do anything, it successfully autoconnects seemingly at random.

The Bluetooth notification icon has a slider where I can turn the connection to my headset on or off, but on the Bluetooth system settings the same slider setting is greyed out.

Comment: This bug report might be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1594591